# Metrics to analyse neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to find interesting metrics that can be used to analyse a neural network.

So accuracy (test, and validation error) and computational complexity (space and time) seem like the obvious ones, but are there others?

Why do we know that neural network 1 is better than neural network 2?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by accuracy  (is this a NN for classification?), but I would definitely add cross-validation error.

Comment: Ok, ill edit it and try to be more clear. But that is a good point, the distinction between different types of error (aka accuracy in my books).

Comment: Ah, of course if you're going Bayes, then WAIC and LOO-CV (which is again cross-validation but from a Bayesian perspective): [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04544).

Comment: Are you talking about model error, precision/recall? Or are you talking specifically about metrics describing the _structure_ of an NN? You should give more detail, like an example maybe, of what you want to compare.

Comment: What do you mean by recall, it seems like an interesting notion. 

Um, I think I am interested in metrics not related to accuracy (as I think it is generally well covered and that it is just one facet of NN performance). Also, I was trying not to bias the answers too much as I was interested in pretty much any other way to analyse a NN.

Answer (score 1):

A set of different quality metrics for neural network classifiers have been developed and published in 1994 [1]. The reference is given below.

Besides the usual correctness/accuracy measures, and their class-conditional similar metrics - specific *failure metrics* have were developed. The bias and dispersion measures for the whole classifier, and for each of the classes are presented.
For an application see '[bias- and dispersion-metrics illustrated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339895/can-we-compute-co-variance-using-neural-network/340480#340480)'.

Using the failure metrics, it can be see whether some classes are more likely to be misclassified as specific classes, than a other (wrong) classes.

[1] M. Egmont-Petersen, J.L. Talmon, J. Brender, P. NcNair. "On the quality of neural net classifiers," Artificial Intelligence in Medicine, Vol. 6, No. 5, pp. 359-381, 1994.